# Лицензирование дипломного проекта в университете, какую лицензию выбрать для исходного кода?

Tags: лицензирование

Какую лицензию выбрать для исходных кодов дипломного проекта для того, чтобы университет не мог использовать его в коммерческих целях?

И является ли использование исходных кодов для обучения на коммерческой основе нарушением той же лицензии *GNU GPL v3*?

Comment: К сожалению ответа у меня для вас нет, но может быть материал отсюда поможет, [licenseit.ru](http://licenseit.ru/wiki/index.php/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Comment: Поясните вторую часть вопроса. Кто использует, зачем и как?

Comment: @rjhdby использоваться будет в библиотеке, я не против свободного распространения, но против использования материалов в коммерческих целях таких как обучение на платной основе и т.п.

Comment: @Sam_Fisher для начала я бы узнал, свободны ли вы вообще в выборе лицензии. Вполне возможно, что любой продукт выпущенный вами в рамках обучения, принадлежит учебному заведению. Надо договор и законы курить.По поводу использования свободных материалов для обучения на платной основе - авторство не присвоено, продукт не продан(чека нет, проще говоря), исходники предоставляются...

Comment: Этот вопрос юридический, не технический, и задать его лучше юристу, а не нам.

Comment: Универсистет не может использовать исходные коды вашего проекта даже в некоммерческих целях. Это по закону. А на практике никто законы не соблюдает. Поэтому дополнительно лицензировать ничего не надо.

Comment: @uorypm Зависит от договора на обучение, который подписывал автор вопроса

Answer (score 4):

> является ли использование исходных кодов для обучения на коммерческой основе нарушением той же лицензии GNU GPL v3?

нет, не является.

[стандартные общественные лицензии gnu](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/licenses.ru.html#GPL), к которым относится и *третья версия gnu gpl*, не налагают никаких ограничений на **цели** использования программ, **скомпилированных** из исходников, распространяющихся под этими лицензиями. а уж про цели использования самих исходных текстов и речи нет. но, разумеется, при опубликовании этих исходных текстов [должно быть](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.ru.html) и упоминание про лицензию, под которой они распространяются.

> Какую лицензию выбрать для исходных кодов дипломного проекта для того что-бы университет не мог использовать его в коммерческих целях?

образцов подобных ограничивающих лицензий очень много.

из наиболее, пожалуй, известных — несколько лицензий из набора [*creative commons*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons#.D0.A2.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.83.D1.89.D0.B8.D0.B5), в названии которых фигурирует *NC* (non-commercial).

Comment: А может ли кто либо использовать исходники из моего проекта в коммерческих проектах, разработках ? Если они с лицензией GNU GPL v3

Comment: @Sam_Fisher, http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLCommercially